# Using X-editable within UI.Bootstrap tab-heading directive in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, x-editable

I have a AngularJs App where we use UI.Bootstrap Tabs to create and delete workspaces.
I'm wanting to use X-editable to edit the name of the workspace/tab but within the tab-header directive:

```
<tab-heading>
    <span editable-text="item.title">{{item.title}}</span>
</tab-heading>
```

As it is, it comes up with an inline edit on-click, but does not update the scope on save.

Heres' the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RDfTu/

Comment: I have the same problem. I submitted an issue for this since no one else seems to know a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the generated html:

```
<tabset class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
```

Isolated scopes don't inherit from any scope, so your "item.title" doesn't exist in this scope nor on any scope below it, where your tab headers are, and where x-editable is creating it's controller.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Is there any work around for that issue that doesn't involve changing code from any of the third party libraries (like angular)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it doesn't look like there will be one to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case i was able to solve it using `blur` attribute :

```
<tab-heading>
   <span editable-text="tab.name" onbeforesave="validate($data)" buttons="no" blur="submit">{{ tab.name}}</span>
 </tab-heading>
```

Please see the [documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#ref-element).

Also please see the below code in `xeditable.js`:

```
if (shown[i]._blur === 'submit') {
        toSubmit.push(shown[i]);
      }
```